# Can't turn XML response into an simplexml object

Tags: simplexml, fogbugz

I asked this question before but I got no answers. I'll try to narrow down the question.
See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870598/having-trouble-getting-fogbugz-api-response-into-a-simplexml-object) 
What's wrong with this code:

```
$url = "http://.../fogbugz/api.asp?cmd=logon&email=" . $_UN . "&password=" . $_PW;
$resp = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));
```

Yields:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [token] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

If I output the response of file_get_contents directly to the screen using a header I see the response is correct and the token element is filled with a valid token. Yet simplexml doesn't seem to be able to read the token.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SimpleXML is able to parse CDATA sections and since most of what the FogBugz XML API returns is UTF-8 data, it is put into XML CDATA blocks.  Your browser might be hiding that from you, but if you look at the raw info return from `cmd=logon`, I believe it is a CDATA.